# Importing CSV data into separate MYSQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv

I have a CSV file that with data of the format:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID,DEPARTMENT_NAME,MANAGER_ID,LOCATION_ID,,,,,,,
10,Administration,200,1700,,,,,,,
20,Marketing,201,1800,,,,,,,
50,Shipping,124,1500,,,,,,,
60,IT,103,1400,,,,,,,   
    ,Table 1: Departments Table,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,

EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,
COMM_PCT,MGR_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID
100,Steven,King,SKING,234.8023.45671,17-Jun-87,AD_PRES,24000,,,90
101,Neena,Kochhar,NKOCHHAR,234.8034.45686,21-Sep-89,AD_VP,17000,,100,90
102,Lex,De Haan,LDEHAAN,234.8053.45694,13-Jan-93,AD_VP,17000,,100,90

 ,,,Table 2: Employees Table,,,,,,,
```

How do I import these records into two separate sql tables: employees and departments? I've tried the LOAD DATA INFILE syntax but I'm still not able to achieve it. I'm aware that I can edit the CSV file and try to format it but I'm imagining a scenario where I have millions of records and that would be difficult to achieve. Is it even possible to load this data into two tables as it is using just SQL?

Comment: Can you split the CSV into two separate files? From what you've shared, I would handle this by splitting the data into two files: `employees.csv` and `departments.csv`. I would then write a script in Python, C#, Java, or some other common programming language you're comfortable with to handle the database inserts. Let's figure out what resources are available to you so we can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.  LOAD DATA INFILE only supports loading one file to one table.

If you want suggestions on alternate ways to accomplish, let me know.

Comment: Thanks. Please suggest alternate ways to accomplish.

Comment: My recommendation would be to use PHP. PHP is very simple and straightforward when it comes to opening and operating on files. You could open the file with PHP and save the top X rows as a new csv. Then delete those rows and repeat. Then load each file into a sepaeate table.